# How to get the Request object in an EJB based Web Service

Tags: web-services, ejb

Unlike JAX-WS web services, I couldn't get the SOAP request object in an EJB based Web Services, by the way, I am using Oracle Application Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use @Resource to inject WebServiceContext into the EJB.

Comment: Thanks bkail,
Actully i've tried the bellow code:
@Resource WebServiceContext wsContext;
@WebMethod public String getIp() {
MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
return req.getRemoteAddr();
}
But i get this error when i invoke the EJB base web service:
type : javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext
description :
;nested exception is: java.lang.InstantiationException: Error looking up reference resource-env-ref      : 
name : com.sb.BaePcnBean/wsContext
type : javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext
description:

Comment: If there are no other errors (that perhaps point to a restriction I'm unaware of), this looks like a product bug.